# Arduino unable to wake up using interrupt after sending SMS

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, gsm, ds3231-alarms

my use case is that I am building a distance sensor using Arduino Uno. The idea is when the distance is between a threshold, an SMS is sent from the device.

I am using DS3231, SIM800L, and HCSR04 for my needs.

I want to save power consumption too so I am trying to put my Arduino into a deep sleep and then wake up using RTC interrupt.

The code below works fine when the distance is NOT in the threshold. Meaning Arduino is waking up by the interrupt and then doing what it needs to do. However, if the distance is in between the threshold the SMS is sent and received but after that Arduino never wakes up again. I checked out the SQW pin DS3231, using a multimeter and the signal indeed is going LOW, but Arduino does not wake up again.

Libraries that I am using,
[ds3231](https://github.com/rodan/ds3231), [Sim800l](https://github.com/vittorioexp/Sim800L-Arduino-Library-revised), [NewPing](https://bitbucket.org/teckel12/arduino-new-ping/wiki/Home)

Here is the code that I am using,

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <wire.h>
#include <ds3231.h>
#include <NewPing.h>
#include <Sim800L.h>

#define WAKEUP_PIN 2  // when low, makes 328P wake up, must be an interrupt pin (2 or 3 on ATMEGA328P)
#define LED_PIN 13  // output pin for the LED (to show it is awake)

#define TRIGGER_PIN 7
#define ECHO_PIN 6
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200 //max distance we want to measure in cm
NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE);


// DS3231 alarm time
uint8_t wake_HOUR;
uint8_t wake_MINUTE;
uint8_t wake_SECOND;

static boolean goToSleep = false; //to track the when to go to sleep and when to get data and do stuff

#define SIM_MODULE_RX 10
#define SIM_MODULE_TX 11
Sim800L gsmModule(SIM_MODULE_RX, SIM_MODULE_TX);


///* A struct is a structure of logical variables used as a complete unit
// struct ts {
//    uint8_t sec;         /* seconds */
//    uint8_t min;         /* minutes */
//    uint8_t hour;        /* hours */
//    uint8_t mday;        /* day of the month */
//    uint8_t mon;         /* month */
//    int16_t year;        /* year */
//    uint8_t wday;        /* day of the week */
//    uint8_t yday;        /* day in the year */
//    uint8_t isdst;       /* daylight saving time */
//    uint8_t year_s;      /* year in short notation*/
//#ifdef CONFIG_UNIXTIME
//    uint32_t unixtime;   /* seconds since 01.01.1970 00:00:00 UTC*/
//#endif
//};
struct ts t;

// When WAKEUP_PIN is brought LOW this interrupt is triggered FIRST (even in PWR_DOWN sleep)
void sleepISR()
{
    // Prevent sleep mode, so we don't enter it again, except deliberately, by code
    sleep_disable();

    // Detach the interrupt that brought us out of sleep
    detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(WAKEUP_PIN));

    // Now we continue running the main Loop() just after we went to sleep
}

// Double blink just to show we are running. Note that we do NOT
// use the delay for the final delay here, this is done by checking
// millis instead (non-blocking)
void doBlink()
{
    static unsigned long lastMillis = 0;

    if (millis() > lastMillis + 1000)
    {
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
        delay(10);
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
        delay(200);
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
        delay(10);
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
        lastMillis = millis();
    }
}

// Set the next alarm
void setNextAlarm(void)
{
    // flags define what calendar component to be checked against the current time in order
    // to trigger the alarm - see datasheet
    // A1M1 (seconds) (0 to enable, 1 to disable)
    // A1M2 (minutes) (0 to enable, 1 to disable)
    // A1M3 (hour)    (0 to enable, 1 to disable)
    // A1M4 (day)     (0 to enable, 1 to disable)
    // DY/DT          (dayofweek == 1/dayofmonth == 0)
    uint8_t flags[5] = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1};

    // get current time so we can calc the next alarm
    DS3231_get(&t);

    wake_SECOND = t.sec;
    wake_MINUTE = t.min;
    wake_HOUR = t.hour;

    // Add a some seconds to current time. If overflow increment minutes etc.
    wake_SECOND = wake_SECOND + 10;
    if (wake_SECOND > 59)
    {
        wake_MINUTE++;
        wake_SECOND = wake_SECOND - 60;

        if (wake_MINUTE > 59)
        {
            wake_HOUR++;
            wake_MINUTE -= 60;
        }
    }

    // Set the alarm time (but not yet activated)
    DS3231_set_a1(wake_SECOND, wake_MINUTE, wake_HOUR, 0, flags);

    // Turn the alarm on
    DS3231_set_creg(DS3231_CONTROL_INTCN | DS3231_CONTROL_A1IE);
}

void getDistance(){
    
    // Send ping, get distance in cm
    float distance = sonar.ping_cm();
    
    // Send results to Serial Monitor
    Serial.print("Distance = ");
    
    Serial.print(distance);
    Serial.println(" cm");
    delay(500);

    if (distance < 10.00)
    {
        //Setup Sim800 for sms sending
        gsmModule.begin(9600);
        bool err = gsmModule.sendSms("+91790xxxxxxx", "CLose");
        Serial.println(err);
        gsmModule.end();
        delay(3000);
    }
    

    //sleep arduino after the above operation
    goToSleep = true;
}



// Standard setup( ) function
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    // Keep pins high until we ground them
    pinMode(WAKEUP_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);

    // Flashing LED just to show the µController is running
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
    pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);

    // Clear the current alarm (puts DS3231 INT high)
    Wire.begin();
    DS3231_init(DS3231_CONTROL_INTCN);
    DS3231_clear_a1f();


    Serial.println("Setup completed.");
}


// The loop blinks an LED when not in sleep mode
void loop()
{

    // Just blink LED twice to show we're running
    doBlink();

    // Is the "go to sleep" pin now LOW?
    if (goToSleep == true)
    {
        // Set the DS3231 alarm to wake up in X seconds
        setNextAlarm();

        // Disable the ADC (Analog to digital converter, pins A0 [14] to A5 [19])
        static byte prevADCSRA = ADCSRA;
        ADCSRA = 0;

        /* Set the type of sleep mode we want. Can be one of (in order of power saving):
         SLEEP_MODE_IDLE (Timer 0 will wake up every millisecond to keep millis running)
         SLEEP_MODE_ADC
         SLEEP_MODE_PWR_SAVE (TIMER 2 keeps running)
         SLEEP_MODE_EXT_STANDBY
         SLEEP_MODE_STANDBY (Oscillator keeps running, makes for faster wake-up)
         SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN (Deep sleep)
         */
        set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
        sleep_enable();

        // Turn of Brown Out Detection (low voltage)
        // Thanks to Nick Gammon for how to do this (temporarily) in software rather than
        // permanently using an avrdude command line.
        //
        // Note: Microchip state: BODS and BODSE only available for picoPower devices ATmega48PA/88PA/168PA/328P
        //
        // BODS must be set to one and BODSE must be set to zero within four clock cycles. This sets
        // the MCU Control Register (MCUCR)
        MCUCR = bit(BODS) | bit(BODSE);

        // The BODS bit is automatically cleared after three clock cycles so we better get on with it
        MCUCR = bit(BODS);

        // Ensure we can wake up again by first disabling interupts (temporarily) so
        // the wakeISR does not run before we are asleep and then prevent interrupts,
        // and then defining the ISR (Interrupt Service Routine) to run when poked awake
        noInterrupts();
        attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(WAKEUP_PIN), sleepISR, LOW);

        // Send a message just to show we are about to sleep
        Serial.println("Deep Sleep");
        Serial.flush();

        // Allow interrupts now
        interrupts();

        // And enter sleep mode as set above
        sleep_cpu();

        // --------------------------------------------------------
        // µController is now asleep until woken up by an interrupt
        // --------------------------------------------------------

        // Wakes up at this point when WAKEUP_PIN is brought LOW - interrupt routine is run first
        Serial.println("Awake");

        // Clear existing alarm so int pin goes high again
        DS3231_clear_a1f();

        // Re-enable ADC if it was previously running
        ADCSRA = prevADCSRA;

        goToSleep = false; //reset so that arduino does what it needs to do

    }
    else
    {
        
        //check if distance is less
        Serial.println("Checking");
        getDistance();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would first remove all that just-for-sure code like the interrupt handler, repeated attach and detach, interrupts disabling,  BOD

Comment: @Juraj  Not sure how that would help cause the moment I remove the `if (distance < 10.00)` block everything works as expected. (Arduino wakes up every 10 seconds, gets the distance and sleeps, the cycle continues)